# Excel VBA combobox doesn't allow to select specific items from list

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a combobox in my worksheet with a dynamic search, the dynamic search is done by searching the typed letters in a list that is on another worksheet. The search is done by excel formulas. The list is a defined range and then the combobox listfillrange is set to the named range.
When I type the dropdown list opens, for certain items the combobox allows me to select from the list and for others the selection disappear as I select. I tried figure why do these items disappear. The list is long (10,000 items) so it kind of works slow, but I am not sure if this is the problem.

How can I fix such a problem? Is there a way to define a variable for the mouseclick selection from dropdown list?

Thanks in advance,
Tali

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Sheets("PS").EnableCalculation = True
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "DropDownList"
    ComboBox1.DropDown

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim PS As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
    Sheets("PharmaSoft").Select
    Set PS = Sheets("PS")
    SelectionA = PS.Range("J2").Value
   If ComboBox1.Value = SelectionA Then
    Range("J19") = "Pharmacy purchase price"
    Range("N19") = PS.Range("K2")
    Range("O19") = "ILS"
    Range("J21") = "Pharmacy selling price Incl.VAT"
    Range("N21") = PS.Range("L2")
    Range("O21") = "ILS"
    Range("J23") = "Package size"
    Range("N23") = PS.Range("M2")
    Range("J19:O23").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Range("N19").Errors.Item(1).Ignore = True
        Range("N21").Errors.Item(1).Ignore = True
        Range("N23").Errors.Item(1).Ignore = True
   Else
     MsgBox "Please select a product", vbCritical, "Error"
   End If
   Sheets("PS").EnableCalculation = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("PharmaSoft").Select
    ComboBox1.Value = Null
    Range("J19:O23").Value = Null
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Also the code for the workbook:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("PharmaSoft").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("PharmaSoft").ComboBox1.Value = Null
    Range("J19:O23").Value = Null
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: please add some data examples or screen shots and your code

Comment: so what type of controls are you using and what code is where? I mean: are ComboBox1 and all buttons _ActiveX_ controls or _Forms_ ones? Is "PS" the name of the worksheet where ComboBox1 is placed? Which workbook does "PS" sheet belong to? Which worksheets are buttons placed in? Which workbook does `Workbook_Open()` belong to?

Comment: I use only ActiveX controls not forms. The code is in a worksheet called "Pharmasoft" where I display a sort of google search field with a buttons to search and clear the data."PS" is where the list of items and where it calculates the list for the combobox. The workbook_open in defined for the whole workbook.

Comment: so what's the _"another worksheet"_?

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't comment on what you're doing given that your search is done as you mention with excel formulas.  I do know that using data validation via a combo box can be pretty quick.  The method I use is as per this [page](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal10.html) and is extremely fast.  It's pretty much instantaneous on a validation range that is about 15k rows long.  The best part about it is that it provides auto completion.  So when you type in the combo box and that value isn't in the list, the entry that matched one character ago disappears.  It's a good visual cue whether you're selection is valid or not.  And of course, you can still use the drop down box in the usual way.  The only down side is that, as coded at the link provided, you have to double-click to enter the auto-completion mode.

Comment: Thank you, but I am using a searchable field and not autocomplete. If there are two options for a specific work like "Tom skuller" and "Tom Blum" I would like to have both options when I type "Tom". The problem is that I see both names in the list but I can select one name but I can't select the other.

Comment: Don't know if this is the source of the error but when changing the ListValueRange you should do this: 'ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=DropDownList".  Are you changing 'DropDownList'?